# how explain awkward sentence structure to non-native english speaker

Tags: syntactic-analysis, it-its-itself

THis is the title of a medical paper. I'm trying to explain why to non-native english speaker that its awkward (to me anyway). Any suggestions?

Different measures for the cochlear parameters and its correlation with cochlear duct length

Better: Measurement of cochlear parameters for automatic calculation of the cochlear duct length

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. If I understand your question correctly, you are observing that "its" is singular while "measures" is plural. Normally I would explain this as "Agreement," but this is a paper title, and not a sentence. BTW, I would not change the title to "automatic calculation of cochlear duct length." The author was not automatically calculating it. Rather, s/he his looking for statistical correlation between other cochlear parameters.

Comment: How exactly do you measure a parameter? And how do either measurements or parameters (the reference is ambiguous) provide an automatic calculation of length? The sentence is very confusing, for reasons far greater than just singularity versus plurality. In my mind, the sentence should simply read something like the following: ***Measuring cochlear duct length.*** All of the extra words seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: Assuming *you* are a native speaker, you should really fix all the mistakes you made in this post. It makes it easier to understand.